# Is there a way to avoid network traffic on Web API web services hosted in IIS by accessing your services through localhost?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

We have added a Web API services layer to our application to help share the code with various product teams at my client's company. I like this as a way of managing versioning and for code organization but I'm concerned about violating Martin Fowlers *First Law of Distributed Object Design*, namely don't distribute your objects. We can host all of the various products on the same box currently and I was wondering if having the client application access our web services through localhost would allow us to avoid the issues that Martin is calling out. If it was WCF I would configure the end point to use Named Pipes and I guess I'm trying to figure out how to do that in IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are hosting all your projects under the same process, it would be possible to go in-memory but I am not sure how much this makes sense. Here is a good example:

- [Batching Handler for ASP.NET Web API](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2012/06/batching-handler-for-web-api.html)
- [A related post for the above one](http://trocolate.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/mitigate-issue-260-in-batching-scenario/)

It demonstrates the usage of in-memory hosting the entire Web API pipeline. However, in your case, it seems that this won't work out but might be worth considering.